# What happened to our Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-apps-marketplace

Our Chrome Extension was removed from the Google Chrome store (and Google Marketplace) and we didn't get any notification before hand that it was going to be removed, and didn't get notified that it was removed (or for what reason).

Our extension is FollowUp.cc (a growing company that depends on the extension)

One of our engineers started reverting changes and republished an older version of the extension in hopes that that may help.  We're out of ideas.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe the extension was sending some usage statistics by default and it was considered harmful security-wise by the moderators? Anyway without seeing the actual code one can only guess... Like maybe they've decided that it `disrupts the services by Google`.

Comment: Yeah, great question.  I've checked and haven't found any warning emails from them either.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only Google can say why it was taken down.

Comment: You can contact the CWS developer support at this form: https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support

Comment: Excellent, thanks everyone.  I contacted them through the support form, their appeals form, and hit them up on Twitter as well.  Our extension has been down for over a day, and that's how we pay our bills!  We do our best to have a tight and secure extension, so this was a bit of a shock.  If they would have sent us a warning email, we would have fixed whatever problem there was immediately.  That said, I guess we'll be waiting =)